# Slideshow Pagination Javascript/Jquery with no plugins

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Code here https://jsfiddle.net/bbayo/gmvex82e/4/

I want to make a pagination slideshow out of the menu like (skinny, straight, flare) give the slideshow a control example arrows and x to close. I did something but get stuck.

Right now if you click on skinny you will get a slideshow but if you instead click on straight or boyfriend it gives you the content but no arrows.

check it here https://jsfiddle.net/bbayo/gmvex82e/4/

```
<div class="denim-destination-container">
  <div class="denim-destination-content">
    <div class="fits">
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please try to ask clear questions. I don't belive if somebody can understand what are you trying to ask.

Comment: I hope that's clear @Trix

Comment: I think you want to do something like user click menu will show a popup div with http://www.jssor.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-slider.html inside?

Comment: Yes @LinYuan that's exactly what i want to make and the code is in the link above

Comment: @conradk i do have a running code. Here is the sample code https://jsfiddle.net/bbayo/gmvex82e/4/

Comment: @LinYuan i dont want a plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Your post didn't show your entire code to figure out what you're facing and others can't understand what you want to ask.(Although you post the code in jsfiddle, but what you post here is simple html and it's not clear enough for others to understand your question)

2.Why your control arrows and close button didn't show is because your `.hide` contains your control

```
<div id="macysSlideshow" class="hide">
<div id="macysSlideshowWrapper" >
    <div id="skinny" class="macysSlide show">
        <div class="slide-container">
            <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- and more divs -->
</div>
<div class="denim-close " id="x-img">
    <a href="#fits"><img src="xxx"/></a>
</div>
<div class="arrow" id="arrow_right">
    <img src="xxx"/>
</div>
<div class="arrow" id="arrow_left">
    <img src="xxx"/>
</div>
```

and your javscript control show only your slider div but not your control div.

```
$(".link").click(function() {    
$(".hide").hide();
var dataType = $(this).attr('data-type');
   $("#" + dataType).show();
});
```

here is the fixed code.

check the html and javascript section.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link").click(function() {
    $(".hide").hide();
    $(".control").show();
    var dataType = $(this).data('type');
    $("#" + dataType).show();
  });

  var currentPosition = 0,
    counter = 0,
    slideWidth = 886,
    slides = $('.macysSlide'),
    numSlides = slides.length,
    selectedClass;

  function displayArrows(position) {

    for (var i = 0; i < numSlides; i += 1) {
      if (i == position) {
        $(".activeslide").remove();
      } else {
        $("li.navPos" + i).css('color', '#8a8a8a');
      }
    }
  }

  function moveSlide() {
    console.log(slideWidth);
    console.log(currentPosition);
    $('#macysSlideshowWrapper').animate({
      'margin-left': (slideWidth * -currentPosition)
    })
  }

  $('.arrow').click(function() {
    currentPosition = parseInt(currentPosition);
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'arrow_right') {
      if (currentPosition == (numSlides - 1)) {
        currentPosition = 0;
      } else {
        currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
      }
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'arrow_left') {
      if (currentPosition == 0) {
        currentPosition = numSlides - 1;
      } else {
        currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;
      }
    }

    displayArrows(currentPosition);
    moveSlide();
  });

  displayArrows(currentPosition);

  $(".fits-bottom-nav li").click(function() {
    moveSlide();
    //            selectedClass=$(this).attr('class');
    //            console.log('selectedClass', selectedClass);
    //            currentPosition = selectedClass[6];
    currentPosition = $(this).find("a").data('index');
    console.log('currentPosition', currentPosition);
    displayArrows(currentPosition);
    moveSlide();
  });

  $(".control").hide();

});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  /* 24 / 16 */
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* 24 / 16 */
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 32px;
}
.denim-destination-container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 0;
}
.denim-nav ul li a.active {
  color: yellow;
}
.denim-destination-content {
  border-top: 7px solid #34496C;
  border-right: 7px solid #34496C;
  border-left: 7px solid #34496C;
  width: 886px;
  height: 2532px;
}
/* fits styles */

.fits,
.washes {
  position: relative;
}
.fits-top-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  left: 50px;
}
.fits-top-nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 5px;
}
.fits-top-nav li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.fits-bottom-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 576px;
  left: 34px;
}
.fits-bottom-nav li a {
  color: #485977;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: -8px;
}
.fits-bottom-nav .active a {
  background-color: #ccc !important
}
.washes-top-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 512px;
  left: -17px;
}
.washes-top-nav li {
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-left: 20px
}
.washes-top-nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 5px;
}
/* slide styles */

#macysSlideshow {
  /*width and height of the slides go here*/
  height: 636px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 173px;
  clear: both;
}
#macysSlideshowWrapper {
  /*width of all the slides combined (slidesWidth * 3) goes here*/
  /* width:6300px;
         height:636px;*/
}
.macysSlide {
  /*slide with and height goes here*/
  width: 886px;
  height: 636px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
.slide-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 886px;
}
.arrow,
.denim-close {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*add left and right arrow positioning*/

#arrow_left {
  top: 30%;
  left: 15px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#arrow_right {
  top: 30%;
  left: 855px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#x-img {
  top: 1%;
  left: 850px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  z-index: 100;
}
/* BRANDS STYLE */

#brands {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #34496c;
  margin-top: 205px;
}
.brand-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 400px;
}
.dotted {
  border-bottom: 3px dashed #34496c;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.brands-list li {
  display: inline;
}
.brands-list a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 55px;
  color: #34496c;
}
.new-noteworthy-list {
  width: 611px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
.all-time-fav-list {
  width: 580px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
/* how to wear it styles */

label,
a {
  color: teal;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#slider {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* NEW EXPERIMENT */

/* Slider Setup */

input {
  display: none;
}
#slide1:checked ~ #slides .inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}
#slide2:checked ~ #slides .inner {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
#slide3:checked ~ #slides .inner {
  margin-left: -200%;
}
#slide4:checked ~ #slides .inner {
  margin-left: -300%;
}
#slide5:checked ~ #slides .inner {
  margin-left: -400%;
}
#slide6:checked ~ #slides .inner {
  margin-left: -500%;
}
#slide7:checked ~ #slides .inner {
  margin-left: -600%;
}
#overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 774px;
}
article img {
  width: 100%;
}
#slides .inner {
  width: 700%;
  line-height: 0;
}
#slides article {
  /*width: 20%;*/
  float: left;
}
/* Control Setup */

#controls {
  margin: -29.9% 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#controls label {
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
#active {
  /*margin: 20% 0 0;*/
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 175px;
}
#active label {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 35px;
}
#active label:hover {
  background: #eacf54;
  border-color: #777 !important;
}
#controls label {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4),
#slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5),
#slide5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(6),
#slide6:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(7),
#slide7:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1) {
  background: url('../images/denim-right-arr-01.png') no-repeat;
  float: right;
  margin: -190px -20px 0 0;
  display: block;
}
#slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(7),
#slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
#slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#slide5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4),
#slide6:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5),
#slide7:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(6) {
  background: url('../images/denim-left-arr-01.png') no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin: -190px 0 0 15px;
  display: block;
}
#slide1:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}
#slide2:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(3),
#slide4:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(4),
#slide5:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(5),
#slide6:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(6),
#slide7:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(7) {
  background: #eacf54;
  border-color: #eacf54 !important;
}
/* Animation */

#slides .inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -ms-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -o-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  /* easeInOutQuart */
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  /* easeInOutQuart */
}
#slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
#controls label {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}
/*washes styles*/

.washes-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 235px;
  left: 175px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
#dw {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
}
#ww {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}
#bw {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}
#gw {
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
}
#mw {
  position: absolute;
  left: 295px;
}

`HTML`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="denim-destination-container">
  <div class="denim-destination-content">
    <div class="fits">
      <img src="http://www1.mcomexternal114.fds.com/dyn_img/cms_tiles/astra_published/ce/assets/sitelets/denim-destination-plus/denim-destination-plus-02a.jpg" alt="" />
      <div id="macysSlideshow" class="hide">
        <div id="macysSlideshowWrapper">
          <div id="skinny" class="macysSlide show">
            <div class="slide-container">
              <img src="http://www1.mcomexternal114.fds.com/dyn_img/cms_tiles/astra_published/ce/assets/sitelets/denim-destination-plus/denim-destination-plus-04a.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="straight" class="macysSlide show">
            <div class="slide-container">
              <img src="http://www1.mcomexternal114.fds.com/dyn_img/cms_tiles/astra_published/ce/assets/sitelets/denim-destination-plus/denim-destination-plus-05a.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="boyfriend" class="macysSlide show">
            <div class="slide-container">
              <img src="http://www1.mcomexternal114.fds.com/dyn_img/cms_tiles/astra_published/ce/assets/sitelets/denim-destination-plus/denim-destination-plus-06a.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="bootcut" class="macysSlide show">
            <div class="slide-container">
              <img src="http://www1.mcomexternal114.fds.com/dyn_img/cms_tiles/astra_published/ce/assets/sitelets/denim-destination-plus/denim-destination-plus-08a.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="cropped" class="macysSlide show">
            <div class="slide-container">
              <img src="http://www1.mcomexternal114.fds.com/dyn_img/cms_tiles/astra_published/ce/assets/sitelets/denim-destination-plus/denim-destination-plus-07a.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="flare" class="macysSlide show">
            <div class="slide-container">
              <img src="http://www1.mcomexternal114.fds.com/dyn_img/cms_tiles/astra_published/ce/assets/sitelets/denim-destination-plus/denim-destination-plus-09a.jpg" alt="" />

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <div class="denim-close " id="x-img">
          <a href="#fits">
            <img src="http://www1.mcomexternal114.fds.com/dyn_img/cms_tiles/astra_published/ce/assets/sitelets/denim-destination-plus/denim-close.png" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow" id="arrow_right">
          <img src="http://www1.mcomexternal114.fds.com/dyn_img/cms_tiles/astra_published/ce/assets/sitelets/denim-destination-plus/denim-right-arr.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="arrow" id="arrow_left">
          <img src="http://www1.mcomexternal114.fds.com/dyn_img/cms_tiles/astra_published/ce/assets/sitelets/denim-destination-plus/denim-left-arr.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav class="fits-top-nav denim-nav">

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#fits">FITS</a>
          </li>
          <!--
         -->
          <li><a href="#washes">WASHES</a>
          </li>
          <!--
         -->
          <li><a href="#how-to-wear">HOW TO WEAR IT</a>
          </li>
          <!--
         -->
          <li><a href="#brands">BRANDS</a>
          </li>
          <!--
         -->
          <li><a href="#">SHOP ALL DENIM</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav class="fits-bottom-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#skinny" data-index="0" data-type="macysSlideshow" class="link">SKINNY</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#straight" data-index="1" data-type="macysSlideshow" class="link" style="margin-left: 13px;">STRAIGHT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#boyfriend" data-index="2" data-type="macysSlideshow" class="link" style="margin-left: 7px;">BOYFRIEND</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#bootcut" data-index="3" data-type="macysSlideshow" class="link" style="margin-left: 10px;">BOOTCUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#cropped" data-index="4" data-type="macysSlideshow" class="link" style="margin-left: 10px;">CROPPED</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#flare" data-index="5" data-type="macysSlideshow" class="link" style="margin-left: 18px;">FLARE</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @LinYaun. How can i fixed that.

Comment: Lin Thank you so much buddy. I think it's working just like how i wanted it. Do you notice, if i click on cropped or flare sometimes it don't give me the slide for the that unless i click it twice.

Comment: Can you help me with the close button(x). When i click on it X to close the slideshow and take me to main page.